# Master Language: bad value for restricted picklist field: en_IE

Tags: knowledge, topics

I am testing some functionalities of salesforce knowledge, and I'm enabling the topics on some objects that actually doesn't has it enabled.

[image: Enable Topics]

But everytime i try to enable it, i get the error,

> "Master Language: bad value for restricted picklist field: en_IE "

and I'm not understanding what is generating this issue.

Just for the context, I'm using a developer edition.

Comment: You will need to fix all picklist value first. They should not have values other that defined in picklist field.

Comment: @Ashwani actually the environment is the standard one, i didn't changed picklists, or added new ones. Is the default one, i just activated the knowledge part.  What type of fix do you mean?

Comment: Have you enabled the Critical Update to "Disable Access to Lightning Experience and the Salesforce1 mobile browser app from Microsoft Internet Explorer 11"? My gut tells me it could be related to that.

Comment: @crmprogdev I tried to disable all the latests critica updates. But still i have the same issue. Thanks anyway with your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I had the same problem. Please try this: 
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Why-do-I-receive-a-Master-Language-bad-value-for-restricted-picklist-field-error&language=en_US&type=1